# How do I solve this error during testing Costum resnet model?

Tags: python, image, keras, resnet, transfer-learning

I trained Resnet-50 using transfer learning(Keras), training was successful and I saved the model. when I am using the following code to test the model, it does not work, it gives me an error.  How do I solve this error?

```
for i in classes:
    names = class_names[i]
print(names)

key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

the error that I get:

```
**TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: learning_rate**
```

I followed this guy's tutorial to train my model:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBOavqh3kWU

Answer (score 0):

In model.compile(), optimizer='adam' not optimizer='adam)'

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you tensorflow version should be upto date(tf 2.2.0) 2. Import all the methods from tensorflow.keras or keras for training and loading the model because keras and tensorflow.keras both are different. 3. Try to use lr instead of learning_rate if your tensorflow version is less than 2.2.0 4. After making above changes retrain your model and save it to .hdf5 format 5. I'm supposing that you have provided other arguments in model.compile() in same way in string format

Comment: I followed this guy's tutorial to train my model: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBOavqh3kWU

Comment: Are you getting the error even after removing the model.compile() from above code snippet

Comment: yes, I removed this part "model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])" I get the same error.

Comment: 1. Check you tensorflow version should be upto date(tf 2.2.0)                               
2. Import all the methods from tensorflow.keras or keras for training and loading the model because keras and tensorflow.keras both are different.                                               3. Try to use lr instead of learning_rate if your tensorflow version is less than 2.2.0                4. After making above changes retrain your model and save it to .hdf5 format                          5. I'm supposing that you have provided other arguments in model.compile() in same way in string format.

Comment: Thanks dude, the problem was with "from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model" which I changed it to "from keras.models import load_model" and it is working now.